# Is there a way to list a directive as a requirement for another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I use for date-time input and I'd like to use it in the template for another directive.
The problem is that if I use the parent directive anywhere and I forget to include the child directive in the page, it fails silently.
Is there a way to make a directive require another directive?
I tried listing it in the `require` attribute, but then it fails even when `DateTimeInput` is included.

```
angular
.module('main')
.directive("newTransferPane", ["TransferService", function(TransferService){
    'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "Templates/NewTransferPane.html",
        scope: true,
        require: "DateTimeInput",
        link: function ($scope){
            $scope.secondTransfer = false;
            $scope.transfer_date = new Date();

            $scope.$watch("secondTransfer", function(){
                TransferService.secondTransfer = $scope.secondTransfer;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: did you try `require: '^directiveName'`?

Comment: Thanks, @PankajParkar

Comment: I just tried that and it throws the same error. `Controller 'DateTimeInput', required by directive 'newTransferPane', can't be found!`

Comment: because `newTransferPane` directive doesn't have `DateTimeInput` in parent element..

Comment: *and I forget to include the child directive in the page*: that's the problem: make sure not to forget it. A simple way to make it impossible to forget it is to package both directives in a single JS file, and make them part of the same module.

Comment: `DateTimeInput` is a directive that is used in the template of  `newTransferPane`. It is not part of the parent. I see that error even when `newTransferPane` displays properly.

Comment: @JBNizet. I need to use `DateTimeInput` in many other places as well. I understand that I should not forget it, but when I have second or third level dependencies it becomes easy to forget something and I am looking for a way to modularize my code. If I can safely nest directives, that makes things a while lot easier.

Comment: You should revise the way your directives interact with each other to make it reasonable. Since you can `require` the directives on the same or parent element, it is `DateTimeInput` that should require `newTransferPane`, not vice versa.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was clear, `DateTimeInput` and 'newTransferPane` are both directives. One of the form fields in `newTransferPane` is a `DateTeimInput`. It makes no sense to make `DateTimeInput` require `newTransferPane`. Even if it did, how do I make directives require other directives?